# My app is crashing with this weird avc message: avc: denied { open } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c115,c257,c512,c768

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

My app crashes and, on an unexpected crash, it is supposed to send a message to Firebase Crashlytics and also save the crash log to my device. For saving the crash log to the device, I use the uncaughtException method from the following class:

```
public class LogSaver implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final String session;
    private final Context context;

    /**
     *
     * @param session unique String with the format yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss.SSS, the log will be saved
     *                to a folder with this name
     * @param context handle to Android system
     */
    public LogSaver(String session, Context context) {
        this.session = session;
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * the cmd comand is passed to a runtime process and it uses the logcat tool to save the
     * log to the device
     */
    public File saveLogToFile() {
        //to create a Text file name "logcat.txt" in SDCard
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File externalDir = cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File folder = new File(externalDir, session);
        File logFile = new File(folder, "log.txt");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String cmd = "logcat -d -f " + logFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return logFile;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param t thread on which the uncaught exception is
     * @param e the exception we want to create stacktrace for
     */
    public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread t, Throwable e) {
        //Write a printable representation of this Throwable
        //The StringWriter gives the lock used to synchronize access to this writer.
        final Writer stringBuffSync = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringBuffSync);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stacktrace = stringBuffSync.toString();
        printWriter.close();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
            Date date = new Date();
            String filename = "CRASH-LOG-" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".STACKTRACE";

            // Write the file into the folder
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
            File externalDir = cw.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File folder = new File(externalDir, session);
            File reportFile = new File(folder, filename);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(reportFile);
            fileWriter.append(stacktrace);
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, at very random times, my app would sometimes crash and I would not see any crash log on my device or on Firebase Crashlytics. So, I tried to investigate this issue by using the saveLogToFile method from the above class and I call it in the onDestroy method in my MainActivity (extends AppCompatActivity). Here I will obviously not paste the full log but just show the very last few lines which I find suspicious:

```
01-20 16:09:59.101  6454  6454 W FEngine::loop: type=1400 audit(0.0:4273765): avc: denied { open } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c115,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c115,c257,c512,c768 tclass=perf_event permissive=0 app=com.memex.eu
```

Is the above a possible cause for the mysterious crash of my app?

Comment: Send please stacktrace log. avc denide - is a system log from selinux. Selinux can't crush your app.

Comment: There is no stack trace, that's the problem. Crashlytics didn't detect any crash and neither did my uncaught exception handler catch any stack trace